# paginated search results with filters for MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

Does anyone know if there is any tool for MVC that does this out of the box:

http://www.dabs.com/category/computing,laptops-and-netbooks,laptops/11105-54590000-56660000

It's a paginated table with search results and with filters on the left side of the screen.

Comment: By *out-of-the-box* you mean *drag-and-drop without me writing a single line of code* approach? This kind of application development approaches are more specific to classic WebForms rather than ASP.NET MVC. In ASP.NET MVC you get Models, Views and Controllers out of the box and you can do a lot with those 3 notions. It's just that you might need to get your hands a little dirty and write some code.

Comment: user(bignumber) - this would entail a couple of partials, one for the search results table, the other for the 'filters'. The filters would more than likely be emitted from a RenderAction() method and the results via a RenderPartial(). that's my quick take on this, tho to be honest, i think you're being very hopeful to find something so specific to be available **out of any box**. good luck tho..

Comment: By out of the box I mean there is no point on reinventing the wheel. I see there is a WebGrid Helper that does a similar thing but it doesn't include filters. And that Helper is written for ASP.NET MVC3 Darin

Comment: google has about a million results for jQuery grid. That is probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should write your own Views and Partials, however if u just cannot get over the idea that there is nothing you can use "Out of the box" that does everything for you, you might wanna take a look at Telerik mvc controls

http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc.aspx

**again, you should try to write your own "controls", instead of spending your time debugging some vendor's code, you will be spending time improving your coding skills, and you won't be dependent on any particular set of tools that you cannot function without**

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebGrid helper in MVC3. Although it is meant to be used as a table, you can just create one column and format the presentation to look and feel like a list with paging. If that is not an option and you are not interested in purchasing components from Telerik, DevExpress or another vendor, then it's time to roll up the sleeves. :-) Personally, I would try WebGrid helper.